# how to add google compute instances behind aws elb

Tags: amazon-ec2, google-compute-engine

I deployed web instances over google compute engine. managing load balancing with nginx load balancer now. but i want it to be handled with amazon's elb .

can somebody tell me how we could do it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. 
AWS ELB only works for load-balancing traffic among ec2 instances.

Please refer to the follow aws documentation for more details
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elastic-load-balancing.html

Also I am not clear why you would not use google cloud load balancing capability for your google compute engines. You should avoid the additional hops between networks for routing traffic from one netwrok to the other.

Please refer to the following docs for more information:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing-and-autoscaling#policies